macro_rules with simple infix operator (%)
I'm trying to define a very simple macro for more ergonomic processing of serde_json::Value objects. I would like to add more operators over time, after I get this basic one working:
// requires `st: serde_json::Value` to be in scope
macro_rules! std {
    (*$key:expr) => {
        st[$key.to_string()].as_str().unwrap_or_default().to_owned()
    };
    ($a:literal % $b:expr) => {
        st[$a.to_string()].as_str().unwrap_or_default().to_owned() + $b.as_str().unwrap_or_default()
    };
}

I want to use it like this:
std!(*"Address" + " #" % *"StreetAdditionalInfo")
But the above example unfortunately fails with:
cannot calculate the remainder of `&str` divided by `str`

What am I missing?

Order of the clauses is important. They will be matched top to bottom, and as *"Address" + " #" % *"StreetAdditionalInfo" is valid expression (though meaningless) it will always match the first clause in macro and will simply never match second one.

I was hoping it would recursively match sub-expressions inside the main expression... unfortunately looks like I need some token-tree craziness to achieve something like that :-(

And what should happen in case when multiple sub-expressions match the same input?

I imagined it would iteratively or recursively re-resolve until no matches remain. But clearly that's not how it works. I will accept your answer considering it "will simply never match second one"
